# I want to send Transact XCM Message with TransferReserveAsset XCM Message from Relay Chain to Parachain

Tags: parachain, xcm, xcmp

I want to send some extra information ("Call") with the `TransferReserveAsset` Message. As it has an extra field called xcm:-

```
TransferReserveAsset { assets: MultiAssets, dest: MultiLocation, xcm: Xcm<()> }
```

But `reserve_transfer_assets` extrinsic function in `pallet-xcm` doesn't take that as an argument.

So is there any way I can send a `TransferReserveAsset` Message with an extra XCM Message from relay-chain to Parachain?

Answer (score 3):

The `reserve_transfer_assets` call in pallet-xcm is only designed to transfer some assets from the local chain to the sovereign account of a destination chain and forward a notification XCM as you can see in [the source code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L552). It is not meant to send arbitrary XCM messages in it.

If you want to send an arbitrary call as an XCM message from the relay chain you may use the `send` call, where the XCM message to send is of type `Box<VersionedXcm<()>>` as you can see [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/7bfac17f7077997963da866fd972c9034b64c855/xcm/pallet-xcm/src/lib.rs#L466). But bear in mind that the destination chain should be configured to accept and process this XCM message.

Comment: I have a requirement where the user can transfer some DOT to our sovereign account on the relay chain, and at the same time, the user can send some extra information (possibly in the form of a transaction) to our parachain. The issue is that we can use the send_xcm() extrinsic to send the transaction, but it doesn't guarantee the DOT transfer by the user on the relay chain. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I am not sure how feasible to achieve is this from the relay chain point of view as of now (XCM v2).  But I recommend you to open a new question on Substrate Exchange about this, trying to be as detailed as possible about the concrete cross-chain scenario.